# Selective UPDATE Using CASE from two tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, sql-update, case

I have two tables  `Item` and `Measure`.

Item:

```
ItemName    |   Unit    |   Extra5
------------|-----------|--------
bolt        |   PCS     |   
nut         |   M2      |   
Screw       |   M3      |   
Slug        |   JM      |
```

Measure:

```
ItemName    |   Unit    |   QtyPerMeasure
------------|-----------|--------------
bolt        |   PCS     |   1
bolt        |   M2      |   2
bolt        |   M3      |   3
bolt        |   JM      |   4
nut         |   PCS     |   11
nut         |   M2      |   22
nut         |   M3      |   33
nut         |   JM      |   44
Screw       |   PCS     |   111
Screw       |   M2      |   222
Screw       |   M3      |   333
Screw       |   JM      |   444
Slug        |   PCS     |   1.1
Slug        |   M2      |   2.2
Slug        |   M3      |   3.3
Slug        |   JM      |   4.4
```

I need to update field `Extra5` in table `Item` in a way that query selects the corresponding value based on `Unit`.

Result should look like:

```
ItemName    |   Unit    |   Extra5
------------|-----------|--------
bolt        |   PCS     |   1
nut         |   M2      |   22
Screw       |   M3      |   333
Slug        |   JM      |   4.4
```

What I've tried so far:

```
UPDATE 
    Item 
SET 
    Extra5 = 
        CASE (SELECT Unit FROM Item)
        WHEN 'PCS' THEN SELECT Unit FROM Measure WHERE yksikko = 'PCS'
        WHEN 'JM' THEN SELECT Unit FROM Measure WHERE yksikko = 'JM'
        WHEN 'M2' THEN SELECT Unit FROM Measure WHERE yksikko = 'M2'
        WHEN 'M3' THEN SELECT Unit FROM Measure WHERE yksikko = 'M3'
FROM
    Item a
    INNER JOIN Measure b
        ON a.ItemName = b.ItemName
```

This gives me an error :    `Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 16. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.`

I was thinking if `CASE` is after all the correct approach.
Am I going in totally wrong direction?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: When using `CASE` into the format `CASE {value} WHEN {expression}...` you part `{value}` has to be a literal, it can't be an expression, and certainly can't be a dataset.

Comment: `yksikko`? Using `Unit` to find `Unit` and substitute `Unit` looks unproductive. You ought to be able to use `case a.Unit when 'PCS' then ( select m.Unit from Measure as m where m.Unit = a.Unit ) ... end`, but it's quite pointless and involves repeating the literal values (`'PCS'`) when it should all be table-driven. In any event, using one of the answers with `join` is a much better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE I
SET I.Extra5 = M.QtyPerMeasure
FROM Item AS I
INNER JOIN Measure AS M ON M.ItemName = I.ItemName
    AND M.Unit = I.Unit
```

Explanation: Query will update Extra5 column by matching itemname and unit column values of Item and Measure tables.

Comment: Would you be able to add some explanation to your answer, please?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just trying to do this.

```
UPDATE 
    Item 
SET 
    Extra5 = ISNULL(c.Unit, a.Unit)
FROM
    Item a
    INNER JOIN Measure b
        ON a.ItemName = b.ItemName
    LEFT JOIN Measure c 
        ON a.Unit = c.yksikko
```

Comment: I'm not so sure about the `ON a.Unit = c.yksikko`.  There is `Unit` in `Measure` table too.  How do you know you can join it this way?  What about the filtering?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this. Here you can use `inner join` to get your desired result. Then simply update them as per the need. Since `Item_name` and `Unit` are same and combination of this is making unique key to update.

```
UPDATE ITEM
SET ITEM.Extra5 = MEASURE.QtyPerMeasure
FROM Item AS ITEM INNER JOIN Measure AS MEASURE 
ON ITEM.Unit = MEASURE.Unit AND ITEM.ItemName = MEASURE.ItemName
```